# regexp single digit at start of string

Tags: regex

A have following alphanumeric sequence:

```
[9A1 9A10 9B2 10C1]
```

I want to transform it in following way:

```
9A1  --> 096501
9A10 --> 096510
9B1  --> 096601
10C1 --> 106701
```

I need it to perform sorting.
So can't get regexp that matches to only 1 digit at the start of string, e.g.
it should return me following:

```
9A1  --> 9
9A10 --> 9
9B1  --> 9
10C1 -->  {nothing}
```

So I can transform it then to two digit presentation.

I tried following:

```
^[\d]{1}
```

but it works for all cases not for only single digit.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work for a single digit? `^[\d]{1}` should definitely match `1` in `10C1`, and will also match a single digit by itself (such as `1`).

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\d(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/J6R8AB/1

Comment: But I need to get it matched for `1` only in `1A2` but not in `10A2`

Comment: @The fourth bird, yes! Exactly! Thank you! Could you post it as answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match a digit from the start of the string `^\d` and use a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` to assert what is directly on the right is not a digit:

```
^\d(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J6R8AB/2)

Note that `^[\d]{1}` can be written as `^\d` and matches a single digit from the start of the string. It does not take into account what is directly on the right.